# AES - How do I write Inverse Sub Bytes in C++?

Tags: c++, aes

How do I write Inverse Sub Bytes for AES Decryption in C++? I only found Sub Bytes for AES Encryption, which is shown below.

```
void SubBytes(unsigned char* state)
{
    for(int i=0, i<16; i++)
    state[i] = sbox[state[i]];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Programming questions are off-topic here, even if they are about cryptography. The right place to ask programming questions is stackoverflow - allow me to migrate this there for you.

Comment: @EllaRose Alright, thank you and sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am hardly a programmer but you could define an inverse sbox table using the sbox table. define its entries via

> sboxinv[sbox[u]]:=u

as u ranges over 0 to 255.

Then use the same structure as in the code fragment above

```
void InvSubBytes(unsigned char* state)
{
    for(int i=0, i<16; i++)
    state[i] = sboxinv[state[i]];
}
```